# Handling large xml payloads in apache camel cxf

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I am writing a camel proxy route to invoke an external web service. It so happens that the payload of the target service is pretty big. How do I handle this scenario in the route. 
Coming from OSB background, in OSB, this is done by using chunked streaming mode. How can we achieve similar results in Apache camel.

The issue that I am facing with the normal payload data format route is that invocations are failing with Control Character issues as explained in my previous question : [Apache Camel CXF - Error Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53485834/apache-camel-cxf-error-illegal-character-ctrl-char-code-31)

Comment: Did you get any further with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider [Jetty](http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html),
[Servlet](http://camel.apache.org/servlet.html) or
[Http4](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html) (better control on the request) camel components. Theses http endpoints are designed to proxify http requests. With bridgeEndpoint and disableStreamCache options, you can create a http proxy with streaming without loading the payload in memory.

Comment: At the moment, I am using the cxf component to proxy the webservices so that I dont have to construct the Soap response / fault structures. If I use the http4 camel component, would that still be taken care of or would I have to construct the response ...